# Failed while installing JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 1.1 when trying to import maven project

Tags: eclipse, web-services, maven, jax-rs, m2eclipse

I am trying to import a maven project in Eclipse. It gives an error 
"Updating Maven Project. Failed while installing JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 1.1.
'' : unable to configure web module for JAX-RS ". Unable to configure web module for JAX-RS.

Following is the error log from workspace .metadeta. Any suggestion or fixes? Java Version 1.6 and Jersey Version 1.18.1.

```
ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core 4 0 2015-05-14 11:18:28.723
        !MESSAGE Failed while installing JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 1.1.
        !STACK 1
        org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.core.internal.project.facet.JAXRSFacetException: '<project-name>' : unable to configure web module for JAX-RS 
            at org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.core.internal.project.facet.JAXRSFacetInstallDelegate.execute(JAXRSFacetInstallDelegate.java:103)
            at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.callDelegate(FacetedProject.java:1477)
            at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.modifyInternal(FacetedProject.java:441)
            at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.mergeChangesInternal(FacetedProject.java:1181)
            at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject.access$2(FacetedProject.java:1117)
            at org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.internal.FacetedProject$1.run(FacetedProject.java:324)
            at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
        .....
        .....

    at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:77)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxrs.core 4 0 2015-05-14 11:18:28.723
    !MESSAGE '<project-name>' : unable to configure web module for JAX-RS 

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2015-05-14 11:18:28.828
    !MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".
    !STACK 0
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.web.WebAppProvider.getImage(WebAppProvider.java:99)
        at org.eclipse.jst.jee.ui.internal.navigator.Web25LabelProvider.getImage(Web25LabelProvider.java:47)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.findImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:197)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getColumnImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.getImage(NavigatorContentServiceLabelProvider.java:98)
        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.navigator.NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider$StyledLabelProviderAdapter.getImage(NavigatorDecoratingLabelProvider.java:59)
```

Comment: It seems this user has had the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16836832/failed-while-installing-jax-rs-rest-web-services-1-1-java-lang-nullpointerexc

Comment: I don't think it is the same problem. I am also experiencing this. The NullPointerException occurs in a different place.

Comment: did you have any luck with this?